# Can't resolve all parameters for Deploy: (?, ?)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cloud, ionic-cloud-angular

When I am trying to add ionic deploy service on an application I get the Following Error:

[image: ionic deploy service Error]

Answer (score 0):

if you add ***Deploy***  to providers 
please remove it and app will run again

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add Deploy as a provider. The right way for using Deploy with Ionic is defined on this webpage: https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#installation

```
// app.module.ts

import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'APP_ID'
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ ... ],
  providers: [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```